# Is a non-trivial finite perfect group of order 4n?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

A finite group $G$ is *perfect* if $G = G^{(1)} := \langle [G,G] \rangle$, or equivalently, if any $1$-dimensional complex representation is trivial.

*Question:* Is a non-trivial finite perfect group of order a multiple of $4$?

*Remark*: It's true for $\vert G \vert \le 10^6$, by checking with GAP.

Comment: Odd order $n$ is Feit-Thompson's theorem. Order $n\equiv 2[4]$ is because for such a group the signature map of the left action of $G$ on itself is nontrivial.

Comment: @YCor Ahh, that is a way more elementary argument than mine.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : There are various elementary generalizations of YCor's argument. One is the (J.G.) Thompson transfer Lemma: if a finite group $G$ has a subgroup $M$ with $[G:M]$ divisible by $2$, but not $4$, then any involution $t \in G^{\prime}$ is conjugate to an element of $M$. For if not, $t$ acts as a product of an odd number of transpositions in the permutation action of $G$ on the right cosets of $M$.

Comment: Here is a development of the second part of the argument of @YCor: let $G$ be a group of order $n \equiv 2 [4]$, and let $\tau$ be an element of order $2$ (by Cauchy's theorem), the permutation representation of $\tau$ through the action of $G$ on itself is of the form $(g_1,\tau g_1) \dots (g_r,\tau g_r)$ with $r = \vert G \vert /2$, it follows that $sign(\tau) = (-1)^{\vert G \vert /2} = -1$ by assumption. Conclusion $sign(G) = \{-1,1\}$, but this is impossible for a perfect group because $sign([g,h]) = sign(g)^2 sign(h)^2 = 1$.

Comment: @YCor: do you know how to extend the second part of your comment to the fusion categories for answering http://mathoverflow.net/q/211000/34538 ?

Comment: no, I don't know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if the $2$-Sylow subgroup is cyclic then the group has a normal $2$-complement, which is thus a proper normal subgroup with abelian quotient (being of order $2$ in the case where the order is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$).

The above statement follows from Burnside's transfer theorem together with the normalizer/centralizer theorem.

In fact, one can also see in the same way that if $4$ divides the order of the group and $8$ does not, then if the group is perfect it must have order divisible by $3$.

A bit more about the general case: Burnside's transfer theorem states that if the group has a $p$-Sylow subgroup which is central in its normalizer, then the group has a normal $p$-complement. Obviously, if a group has a normal $2$-complement then it is solvable (by Feit-Thompson) and hence not perfect.

To apply it in this situation, we note that if $P$ is the $2$-Sylow then what we need is to show that $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ is trivial, and using that this is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$, what we need to know something about is the order of this automorphism group.

For small orders of $P$, it is easy to give explicit orders for the automorphism groups, but in general, if one wants to make a statement of the form "if $2^m$ is the largest power of $2$ dividing $|G|$ and $G$ is perfect, then $|G|$ is divisible by one of the following primes" one would need to understand the set $X_n$ of odd primes dividing the orders of automorphism groups of groups of order $2^n$, and I don't think much is known about this in general, apart from the obvious fact that $X_n\subseteq X_{n+1}$ (though probably it should be quite possible to say something with the added assumption that the $2$-Sylow is abelian).

Comment: If $2^{n−1}$ divides the order and $2^n$ does not, can you deduce something?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Not much based just on the order. If I get time tomorrow, I will add a bit about the more general case.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Added some extra stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Out of interest, here is another approach to prove that a finite group $G$ which has a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ necessarily has a normal $2$-complement. By induction, it suffices to exhibit a (normal) subgroup of index $2$.
   Consider the regular representation $\rho_{G}$ of $G$. This is a representation of $G$ by permutation matrices, so $\delta(x) = {\rm det} \rho_{G}(x) = \pm 1$ for all $x \in G$. Hence ${\rm ker} \delta$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of index dividing $2$. Hence it suffices to find an element $x \in G$ with $\delta(x) = -1.$

Let $s$ be a generator of $S$. Note that ${\rm Res}^{G}_{S}(\rho_{G}) = [G:S]\rho_{S}$, so that $\delta(s) = \phi(s)^{[G:S]}$, where $\phi(s) = {\rm det} \rho_{S}(s).$ Since $[G:S]$ is odd, it suffices to prove that $\phi(s)= -1$.

Now the eigenvalues of $\rho_{S}(s)$ are all the complex (but not necessarily primitive) $|S|$-th roots of unity, each occurring with multiplicity $1$. 
However, apart from $1$ and $-1$, all other such roots of unity occur in complex conjugate pairs, and each conjugate pair contributes $1$ to the determinant.
Hence $\phi(s) = 1 \times -1 = -1$, as required.